# Question on the no-slipping constraint of a cylinder rolling off another cylinder

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Why is the constraint not $R*\theta_1 = a*\theta_2$? Why isn't the arc length cut out by the smaller cylinder proportional to its angle of rotation?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/xiUDCtX.png]

Answer (score 1):

Let the angle through which the angle of contact rotates be $\theta\ as shown in the diagram.

[image]
 If there had been no slipping then the full and dashed thick black lines are of equal length.

$R\theta_1=a\theta=a(\theta_2-\theta_1)$

Comment: If a=R does that mean $\theta = 0$ ?

Comment: The book is just using a "weird" definition for $\theta_2$. Rather than being the rotation of $a$, it is defined as the rotation of $a$ plus the arc of $R$. For $a=R$, the rotation of $a$ is equal to the arc of $R$, so by the book's definition, $\theta_2 = 2 \theta_1$.

Comment: If $a=R$ then $\theta = \theta_1$ ie both rotate through the same angle..

Comment: @npojo I don't think so actually, it's something about the curve. https://i.imgur.com/rjWC61S.png is another similar question. I think I might repost the question differently

Comment: @Farcher wouldn't that imply that $\theta_2 = 0$?

Comment: I prefer to calculate the velocity at the contact point. No slipping mean velocity equal zero!. This is a pure mathematic calculation, no intuitive. Please look at your disk problem

Answer (score 0):

While the smaller circle traverses one complete revolution (2π-rads), let the angle traversed on the larger cylinder be A-rads. Then RA=2πa. Thus the product of the radius & the angle it traversed is a constant. Hence the angle traversed is inversely proportional to the radius, as against the direct proportionality.

Trust this helps.